# Couchbase 1 -> 2 migration. Backups obtaining and consistency check

Tags: java, web-applications, couchbase, database-migration, database-backups

**Given:** an old Java project using a Couchbase 1. It has a big problem with runtime backups. Both, the simple copying files and the cbbackup way doesn't work. The obtained backups were corrupted, Couchbase doesn't start with them. The only way to obtain data snapshot were a relatively long application shutdown.

Now, we're migrating to the Couchbase 2+. `cbbackup` fails with something like this (*senseless message for me, no any design docs were in the Couchbase 1*):

> /pools/default/buckets/default/ddocs; reason: provide_design done

But, if we use the resulting files, Couchbase seems wake up and works properly.

**Question 1:** Any insights and help with the whole spoiled backups' situation?

**Question 2:** How, at least, we could assure a consistency of the new database backups in our case? 
(*Writing a huge check pack for all docs and fields through the client is very expensive and the last option.*)

I appreciate any help, this is a vague legacy infrastructure for the team, googling and Couchbase documents aren't help us much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Any insights and help with the whole spoiled backups' situation?

Couchbase 1.x used SQlite as the on-disk format (shared into 4 files per Bucket IIRC), which has a number of issues at scale.

One of the major changes in Couchbase 2 was to move to a custom append-only file format (couchstore), which is much less susceptible to any corruption issues (as once written a block is never modified), until a new compacted file is later created by an automated job.

> How, at least, we could assure a consistency of the new database backups in our case? (Writing a huge check pack for all docs and fields through the client is very expensive and the last option.)

If you want to check consistency of the backup you need to do something along the lines of what you mention.

Note however that if you're backing up a live system (as most people are) then the live system is likely to have changed between taking the backup and when you compare it.

As a final aside, I would suggest looking at the [1.8.x to 2.0 Upgrade Guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-1.8/#upgrading-to-couchbase-server-18) on the Couchbase website. Note that 2.x is now pretty old (3.x is current as of writing, 4.0 is in beta) hence the 2.0 documentation is in an archived section of the website.

Comment: Thanks. Could you, please, translate the **docs; reason: provide_design done**? It's really not an error, just a message from 'pump_tap.py', but it always appears after the item failed (without explanation even in verbose mode) by cbbackup.

Comment: "If you want to check consistency..." I hoped, in this DB exists some built-in diagnostics as in mysql, psql, even in SQLite while setting up a backup, maybe a check that all docs or fields are readable or that the resulting JSON is valid JSON, or something similar. Manually we should check only our constraints because the base doesn't know about this ad they're managed by app.